# Google cloud run showing wrong build history

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a google cloud run instance build by a google cloud build trigger,
but in the instance page is showing a wrong build history from another trigger

¿it is posible to change the assigned cloud build trigger to a google cloud run instance?

[wrong trigger history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe3US.png)

I haven't found any solution until now, the last resource it would be delete the cloud run instance and build it again